# Calculus question on rates of change applied to a right-angle triangle

Tags: calculus

I have a right angle-triangle, with adjacent $side = 10 cm,$ opposite site $= x cm$ and base angle $= A.$ I am looking to calculate the rate of change of the opposite side with respect to varying the angle$ A.$

**Attempt.**

$$x= 10\, \tan(A)\quad\implies \quad  \frac{dx}{d A} = 10\, \sec^2(A)$$

When I test this, for example, at A = 45, I get that the rate of change = 20 cm per degree? Which seems way to big?

Am I interpreting this wrong or have I made a mistake with the calculations? Thanks!

Comment: The derivative of tan is only $\sec^2$ if you measure the angle in radians.

Comment: @lulu $10 \sec^2(\pi/4) $ is still $20$, and that doesn't change anything. However, I think what you meant is that the rate of change should be $20$ cm per **radian**, which is $\pi/9$ cm per **degree**.

Comment: @TobyMak  one radian is $57$ degrees.  The OP's (rational) surprise comes from the intuition that changing from $45$ degrees to $44$ could hardly double or triple  $x$.

Comment: Ah I see now! Thank you @lulu,TobyMak